# Importing csv file into python and creating a table in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to import csv file into python and then create a table in python to display the contents of the imported csv file. 
Further need to do manipulations on the data present in the table.
More functions related to table in python should be performed further:
Like:
1) highlighting the specified column using python
2) doing modifications with particular column like sorting data as per the date or quantity using python

Comment: check `read_csv` from `pandas` library ...

Comment: That look awfully like an homework...

Comment: what have you tried so far? besides that it awfully looks like homework, please read how to write a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). IMHO this question does not look like you invested any time in research on e.g. reading files, displaying data (frameworks, etc). Please also keep in mind that SO is no code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example if you want to import a csv file or txt file with Python.
I use Numpy in order to make that :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

file = np.loadtxt('filename', delimiter=',') # Put the delimiter type from your csv file : coma, blank, ..

print file # print the numpy array
```

If you want to make a sort in your array, you can use the numpy function :

```
np.sort()
```

Doc is [there](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

Now, try to make something, because it's important to get a script before to post your ask ;)